# Initialize Flutter widget state with data

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following widget, which requires initializing with some data pulled from a `DataClass` class:

```
class FooWidgetState extends State<FooWidget> {
  List<String> _someUsefulData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _someUsefulData = DataClass.getUsefulData(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: _someUsefulData.map(_buildUsefulWidgets).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

`DataClass` looks like this:

```
class DataClass {
  static List<String> getUsefulData(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      BazLocalizations.of(context).usefulString1,
      BazLocalizations.of(context).usefulString2,
    ];
  }
}
```

and `BazLocalizations` is a class to retrieve localised strings.

The problem is that on running the above code, the following exception is thrown:

> inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_LocalizationsScope) or inheritFromElement() was called before FooWidgetState.initState() completed.

**What I have tried:**

Following the advice [given here](https://www.didierboelens.com/faq/week2/) I wrapped the call in `initState` like this:

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    _someUsefulData = DataClass.getUsefulData(context);
  });
}
```

But then when I try to access `_someUsefulData` in the `build` widget, it is always `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the context to get to that data, you must get your data in the `didChangeDependencies` method, which gets call before the first build.

If you are using Provider you can check out this link: https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider#i-have-an-exception-when-obtaining-providers-inside-initstate-what-can-i-do

If you are not, the same concept applies to InheritedWidgets